# Pandas: How to get the average of all averages in pandas after groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working in Pandas and below is the dataframe

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['A','Excel','1'], ['A','Word','0'], ['A','Java','1'],['B','Excel','1'],['B','Word','0'],['C','Word','0'],['D','Java','1'],['E','PPT','0'], ['E','Word','0'], ['E','Java','1']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['System','App','DevTool'])
```

I obtained the DevTool average for each system using below but how can I get the total average of all averages

```
df.groupby('System')['DevTool'].mean()*100
```

| System | DevTool Ratio |
| --- | --- |
| A | 66.67 |
| B | 50.00 |
| C | 00.00 |
| D | 100.00 |
| E | 33.33 |

Please advice.

Comment: `df['DevTool'].mean()*100` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate an average for a np.array?

Comment: Yes, Jezrael answer made it so simple :)

Comment: So you need separately mean, not append to new `'row'` ?

Comment: both are fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
# initialize list of lists
data1 = [['A','Excel','1'], ['A','Word','0'], ['A','Java','1'],['B','Excel','1'],['B','Word','0'],['C','Word','0'],['D','Java','1'],['E','PPT','0'], ['E','Word','0'], ['E','Java','1']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
dfdf = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['System','App','DevTool'])

#average  System
dfdf['DevTool'] = dfdf['DevTool'].astype('int')
PVT_T = dfdf.pivot_table(index='System', aggfunc={'DevTool':np.mean})

#average all DevTool
dfdf['DevTool'].mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC use:

```
df['DevTool'] = df['DevTool'].astype(int)

s = df.groupby('System')['DevTool'].mean()*100
s.loc['total avg'] = df['DevTool'].mean()*100
```